# Questions about the BBM equation: $-u_{txx}+u_{t}=u_{x}$, $u(x,0)=u_0(x)$, $x,t\in{\bf R}$

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, operator-theory

Consider the [BBM equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benjamin%E2%80%93Bona%E2%80%93Mahony_equation):
$$-u_{txx}+u_{t}=u_{x},\quad u(x,0)=u_0(x),\quad x,t\in{\bf R}$$

One may rewrite it as

$$u_t=((I-A)^{-1}\partial_x)u$$ where $Au=u_{xx}$ if $(I-A)^{-1}$ exists.

Here are my questions:

> 1. Does $(I-A)^{-1}$ always exist?
> 2. Is there an integral operator $K:L^2({\bf R})\to L^2({\bf R})$ such
>      that $K=((I-A)^{-1}\partial_x)$?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

On $L^2(\bf R)$, yes, $(I - \frac{d^2}{dx^2})^{-1}$ exists.  It corresponds via the Fourier transform to multiplication by $1/(1 + p^2)$, and your $K$ corresponds to multiplication by $i p/(1 + p^2)$, or convolution with the inverse Fourier transform of that, namely $i {\rm sgn}(x) e^{-|x|}/2$.